# How can I combine one column and a matrix into a larger matrix with `numpy`?

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to normalize a matrix by doing `(X - means) / variance` to each row.

Since I am implementing this with `MapReduce`, I first calculate the means and standard variance for each column, and then `map` each row with:

```
   matrix.map(lambda X: (X - means) / variance)
```

But I want to ignore the first element in each row `X`, which is my target column containing only 1s and 0s.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If `A` is a numpy array of shape `(m, n + 1)` and you also have arrays `mu` and `s2` of shape `(n,)` holding the mean and variance of each column except the first one, you can do your normalization as follows:

```
A[:, 1:] = (A[:, 1:] - mu) / s2
```

To undestand wat goes on, you need to understand how [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) works. Since `A[:, 1:]` has shape `(m, n)` and `mu` and `s2` shape `(n,)`, these last two have 1s prepended to their shape to match the dimensions of the first, so they are treated as `(1, n)` arrays, and during the arithmetic operations the value in their first and only row is *broadcasted* to all rows.

If you are not already doing so, your meand and variance arrays can be calculated efficiently as

```
mu = (A[:, 1:].mean(axis=0)
s2 = A[:, 1:].var(axis=0)
```

For the variance you may want to use `np.std` squared to take advantage of the `ddof` argument, see the [docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.std.html).

On a separate note, [normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normalization_%28statistics%29) is normally done dividing by the standard deviation, not the variance.

Comment: Thanks. I knew the `mean` and `var` methods, but I think they are just for small datasets. For large datasets, I have to implement them with `MapReduce`. In this case, I need to `map` a row so that the returned `array` are normalized (ignoring the first column).

Comment: `np.concatenate((X[0], (X[1] - mean) / std_var)` is what I want ;)